# How to extract sub strings containing multiple parentheses in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

Is there a regex to extract sub strings from a string containing multiple parantheses?

For example my string is

```
String str = "(A(B(C(D(x)))))";
```

I want to print all the sub strings that lie within any pair of parantheses :

```
  A(B(C(D(x))))
  B(C(D(x)))
  C(D(x))
  D(x)
  x
```

I tried using regex :

```
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

But this only extracts the sub string it finds between 1st pair of parentheses.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to solve this in such way because matching balanced parentheses is not possible with regular expressions. Not with standard syntax (as far as I remember .NET has something for balancing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed what you requested but not just with regex, but a recursive function. Please check following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "(A(B(C(D(x)))))";
    findStuff(str);

}

public static void findStuff(String str){
    String pattern = "\\((.+)\\)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find())
    {
        String sub = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(" Word: " + sub);

        findStuff(sub);
    }
}
```

Comment: But it does not work with this type of string `((A(B))...(C))`